# Buttons in parallel - short circuit?

Tags: microcontroller, resistors, pullup, button, pulldown

I encountered a problem while trying to use 21 buttons at the same time. Initially, I did not take into consideration that they could be pressed all at once. And while measuring the resistance I observed that:

- when pressing 1 button -> resistance 1k
- when pressing 2 buttons at the same time -> resistance 500 ohm, etc.

P.S The buttons have a pulldown of 1 kΩ.

How can you press infinite buttons without eventually having a short circuit?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You could probably use 22 kΩ resistors instead of 1 kΩ. If there were a lot of buttons, you could poll them.

Comment: Once you have more than 5 or 10 buttons, you would usually change the design to a scanned matrix (to save the need for 21 I/O pins (or 103 on a keyboard), such that you have (for example) 3 rows of 7 keys, then at most 7 buttons are powered at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foLcgO.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. What you are describing.*

Yes, you are correct. Pressing multiple buttons adds loading to the power source. It won't be a "short circuit" (which implies that the current is taking a path that bypasses the intended route) but it may overload your voltage source and cause the voltage to droop. With 21 switches all pressed the total load will be < 1k/20 = 50 Ω.

On a 5 V supply this would draw \$ I = \frac V R = \frac 5 {50} = 0.1\ \text A \$. This could easily be enough to cause a problem on a low-current supply or battery.

The solution is to check what current the pull-down needs to sink to ensure a logic 0 on the input of the down-stream device. If, for example, the device sources a current of 0.01 mA and you need < 0.3 V on the input to guarantee a logic 0 then, applying a safety factor of two we can calculate the required pull-down resistance value as
$$ R_{pd} = \frac {V_{LO}} {2I_S} = \frac {0.3}{2 \times 0.01m} = 15\ \text k\Omega$$

Comment: the same applies for pull-ups?

Comment: Of course, but in this case the pull-up needs to **source** the current that the input **sinks**. The maths will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Use 47 k Ohm to 100 k Ohm resistors.

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsuTrY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

How about one resistor and lots of buttons in parallel with each other?

Comment: The usefulness of a circuit with 21 buttons in parallel escapes me. :^)

Answer (score 0):

> *How can you press infinite buttons without eventually having a short
> circuit?*

Well, you can't but, there's a way of ensuring that the current taken by 21 buttons (or 121 or more) is the same as the current taken by 1 button. You have 1 input (with a pull-down resistor) and 21 outputs and sequence through all 21 outputs applying logic 1 to each button in turn. When you input registers a logic 1 then, the output you are currently driving is also the button to which logic 1 is being applied.

Hence, the current drawn is only ever that of 1 button circuit.

To make life easier, you can use a demultiplexer or a decoder. A common one is the 4514: -

[image]

By addressing 4 lines you can control 1 or 16 lines. So, one of these chips can provide the ability to monitor 16 buttons. Cascade two of these chips and you can monitor 32 buttons etc.. Clearly, you have to scan through all the buttons in quick order so that you don't have a sluggish response time but, this shouldn't be a problem for 21 buttons.